# Rename key of typescript object type

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```
type Two = {
  one: number,
  two: string,
  three: boolean
}
```

I want it to create a type that would look like this:

```
type RenamedTwo = {
  one: number,
  two: string,
  four: boolean // difference
}
```

Tried to create it this way:

```
type Rename<T, K extends keyof T, N> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & { [N]: T[K] }
```

In an attempt to use this way:

```
type Renamed = Rename<Two, 'three', 'four'>
```

But TSlint marks `[N]` as error and gives this error message:

> [ts] A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
>   [ts] 'N' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: In case someone wants to rename multiple properties, here is the type definition: `type Rename<T, K extends keyof T, N extends string> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Record<N, valueof<Pick<T, K>>>`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use a mapped type for the renamed property as well:

```
type Two = {
    one: number,
    two: string,
    three: boolean
}


type Rename<T, K extends keyof T, N extends string> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & { [P in N]: T[K] }

type Renamed = Rename<Two, 'three', 'four'>
```

Note that this will not work as expected if you provide more properties:

```
type Renamed = Rename<Two, 'two'  |'three' , 'four' | 'five'> // will be Pick<Two, "one"> & {
//    four: string | boolean;
//    five: string | boolean;
// }
```

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the note. I adjusted the type definition based on your feedback: `type Rename<T, K extends keyof T, N extends string> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Record<N, valueof<Pick<T, K>>>`

Comment: Awesome. TIL you can use `in` operator in a `string` type or Typescript reads it as a union type even if it is of type string?

Answer (score 12):

In the current typescript version 4.6.2, there is a [remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) gramma to use.
It can be implement this much easier.

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2)

```
type RenameByT<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof U as K extends keyof T
    ? T[K] extends string
      ? T[K]
      : never
    : K]: K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never;
};

type Two = { one: number; two: string; three: boolean };

// returnType = { one: number; two: string, four: boolean };
type renameOne = RenameByT<{three: 'four', five: 'nouse'}, Two>;

// returnType = { x: number, y: string, z: boolean; }
type renameAll = RenameByT<{one: 'x', two: 'y', three: 'z'}, Two>;
```

The `RenameByT` type can separate by several parts.
The explain is for the example `renameOne`

1. `K in keyof U` means all the key in `U`. For the example is `one | two | three`
2. [`as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) clause since ts4.1 can use. but i can't use in 4.4.4 but can use in 4.6.2. This is use to rename **Key** `K` by the condiction type
3. `K extends keyof T`. keyof T means `three | five`.
4. `T[K] extends string` means `T[K]` is string. `T['three']` is string so returns `four`, `T['five']` returns `nouse`;
5. the return type `K extends keyof U`, so `T['three']` is satisfy so return `{ four: U['three'] }` means `{ four: boolean}`
6. others keys return as origin

reference:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40833
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: Could or should it be `keyof any` rather than `string`? I.e. a shorthand for `string | number | symbol`.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps worth mentioning that you can solve the OP's original problem without writing a generic type like `Rename`. If you just want to do it once, you could do something much simpler.

```js
type RenamedTwo = { [Property in keyof Two as Property extends 'three' ? 'four': Property]:  Two[Property] }
```