Constructing and typing rich search objects
Background
I am building a Next app that will feature many advanced search forms. I found a library to help construct simple and advanced queries: search-query-parser. search-query-parser will convert an input string like const input = "foo bar -baz answer:42" into an object like const output = { text: ["foo", "bar"], answer: [ "42" ], exclude: { text: [ "baz" ] } } (plus a few other properties). search-query-parser allows specifying keywords and ranges as an array of strings. These will be used to help build the output object. I'm also using zod.
I'm converting this output object in a fully typed object that can be customized for different search forms. The final object will have some common properties for managing pagination and rendering format. It will also contain the raw input string and the fully parsed and typed conditions extracted from the search string.
Mostly Working Solution
import parser, { SearchParserResult } from "search-query-parser";
import { z } from "zod";

const UNPARSED_QUERY_WITH_DEFAULTS = z.object({
    q: z.string().describe("serialized search query").optional().default(""),
    o: z.coerce.number().describe("offset").optional().default(0),
    l: z.coerce
        .number()
        .describe(
            "limit - determines how many results per page (clamp to max value)"
        )
        .optional()
        .default(0),
    e: z.coerce
        .boolean()
        .describe(
            "expand - determines if result set should be expanded to one record per version or collapsed to group multiple versions with the same values"
        )
        .optional()
        .default(false),
    v: z.enum(["list", "table"]).describe("view").optional().default("list")
});

type UnparsedSearchParams = z.infer<typeof UNPARSED_QUERY_WITH_DEFAULTS>;

type Keywords = readonly [string, ...Array<string>];

type Ranges = readonly [string, ...Array<string>];

type RawQuery<
    TKeywords extends Keywords = Keywords,
    TRanges extends Ranges = Ranges
> = SearchParserResult & {
    text?: string[];
} & Partial<Record<TKeywords[number], Array<string>>> &
    Partial<
        Record<
            TRanges[number],
            {
                from: string;
                to?: string | undefined;
            }
        >
    >;

// SEE https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912306/265558
type BulkRename<
    T extends Record<string, string>,
    U extends Record<string, unknown>
> = {
    [K in keyof U as K extends keyof T
        ? T[K] extends string
            ? T[K]
            : never
        : K]: K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never;
};

type Foo = { one: number; two: string; three: boolean };
type Bar = BulkRename<{ one: "first"; two: "second" }, Foo>;

type FullSearchQuery<
    TKeywords extends Keywords = Keywords,
    TRanges extends Ranges = Ranges,
    RenameMap extends Record<string, string> = {}
> = {
    include: Partial<
        BulkRename<
            RenameMap,
            Record<"text" | TKeywords[number] | TRanges[number], unknown>
        >
    >;
    exclude?: Partial<
        BulkRename<
            RenameMap,
            Record<"text" | TKeywords[number] | TRanges[number], unknown>
        >
    >;
};

const buildSearchQuery = <
    RenameMap extends Record<string, string> = {},
    TKeywords extends Keywords = Keywords,
    TRanges extends Ranges = Ranges,
    ExtractConditions extends (
        rawQuery: RawQuery<TKeywords, TRanges>
    ) => FullSearchQuery<TKeywords, TRanges, RenameMap> = (
        rawQuery: RawQuery<TKeywords, TRanges>
    ) => FullSearchQuery<TKeywords, TRanges, RenameMap>
>(
    searchParams: UnparsedSearchParams,
    keywords: TKeywords,
    ranges: TRanges,
    extractConditions: ExtractConditions
) => {
    const query = parser.parse(searchParams.q, {
        offsets: true,
        tokenize: true,
        keywords: [...keywords],
        ranges: [...ranges],
        alwaysArray: true
    }) as RawQuery<TKeywords, TRanges>;

    return {
        ...searchParams,
        conditions: extractConditions(query),
        query
    };
};

const KEYWORDS = [
    "edition",
    "version",
    "is-earliest-in-cycle",
    "is-latest-in-cycle",
    "is-latest"
] as const;

const RANGES = ["cycle"] as const;

const BOOL = z.coerce.boolean().optional();

const releaseConditions = (
    rawQuery: SearchParserResult & {
        text?: string[];
    } & Partial<Record<(typeof KEYWORDS)[number], Array<string>>> &
        Partial<
            Record<
                (typeof RANGES)[number],
                {
                    from: string;
                    to?: string | undefined;
                }
            >
        >
) => ({
    include: {
        text: rawQuery.text,
        edition: rawQuery.edition,
        version: rawQuery.version,
        cycle: rawQuery.cycle,
        isEarliestInCycle: BOOL.parse(
            rawQuery["is-earliest-in-cycle"]?.[
                rawQuery["is-earliest-in-cycle"].length - 1
            ]
        ),
        isLatestInCycle: BOOL.parse(
            rawQuery["is-latest-in-cycle"]?.[
                rawQuery["is-latest-in-cycle"].length - 1
            ]
        ),
        isLatest: BOOL.parse(
            rawQuery["is-latest"]?.[rawQuery["is-latest"].length - 1]
        )
    },
    exclude: rawQuery.exclude
});

type Params = { [key: string]: string | Array<string> };

interface PageProps {
    params?: Params;
    searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | Array<string> | undefined };
}

const searchParams: PageProps["searchParams"] = {};

const searchParamsWithDefaults =
    UNPARSED_QUERY_WITH_DEFAULTS.parse(searchParams);

const releaseQuery = buildSearchQuery<{
    "is-earliest-in-cycle": "isEarliestInCycle";
    "is-latest-in-cycle": "isLatestInCycle";
    "is-latest": "isLatest";
}>(searchParamsWithDefaults, KEYWORDS, RANGES, releaseConditions);

releaseQuery.conditions.include;
//                      ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.version;
//.                             ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.cycle;
//.                             ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.isLatest;
//.                             ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.exclude;
//                      ^?

At the bottom of the code are some type checks. The runtime behavior in my app is actually correct according to console.log. releaseQuery is an example of the kind of search object I'm trying to build. The specific shape of releaseQuery.conditions.include and releaseQuery.conditions.exclude will vary based on configuration and actual input.
What I'd Like Help With
I'm having trouble typing the final output object, specifically regarding releaseQuery.conditions.include properties.

The property names are taken from the input keywords and ranges. I searched and found a type to rename properties based on a simple mapping, but it's not working. Ideally the final property names would be reflected so I don't have to rename them twice.
Property names don't currently auto-complete. I did have a version where the names would auto-complete, but the suggestions were based on keywords and ranges, not what was actually available.
The property values are all typed as unknown. I'd like for these to be inferred by what releaseConditions actually returns.
releaseConditions should be typed to require include and exclude properties. If an explicit property rename type parameter must be specified, it should help inform the names of the these two properties.

That's all I can think of for now. I've been refining this for many days and several hours today, and my brain is fried. I'm happy to answer any clarifying questions if you have some. Thanks!

I figured out how to get everything I wanted. Property names are customizable per form. I get full type-safety and auto-complete internally to SEACH_QUERY and releaseInclude and externally when using the final object.
import parser, { SearchParserResult } from "search-query-parser";
import { z } from "zod";

type Keywords = readonly [string, ...Array<string>];

type Ranges = readonly [string, ...Array<string>];

type RawQuery<
    TKeywords extends Keywords = Keywords,
    TRanges extends Ranges = Ranges
> = SearchParserResult & {
    text?: string[];
} & Partial<Record<TKeywords[number], Array<string>>> &
    Partial<
        Record<
            TRanges[number],
            {
                from: string;
                to?: string | undefined;
            }
        >
    >;

type Include = {
    text?: Array<string>;
    [key: string]: unknown;
};

export const SEACH_QUERY = <
    TKeywords extends Keywords = Keywords,
    TRanges extends Ranges = Ranges,
    TInclude extends Include = Include
>(
    keywords: TKeywords,
    ranges: TRanges,
    extractInclude: (rawQuery: RawQuery<TKeywords, TRanges>) => TInclude
) =>
    z
        .object({
            q: z.string().optional().default("").catch(""),
            o: z.coerce
                .number()
                .nonnegative()
                .int()
                .optional()
                .default(0)
                .catch(0),
            l: z.coerce
                .number()
                .nonnegative()
                .int()
                .optional()
                .default(0)
                .catch(0),
            e: z.coerce.boolean().optional().default(false).catch(false),
            v: z
                .enum(["list", "table"])
                .optional()
                .default("list")
                .catch("list")
        })
        .transform(({ q, o, l, e, v }) => {
            const query = parser.parse(q, {
                offsets: true,
                tokenize: true,
                keywords: [...keywords],
                ranges: [...ranges],
                alwaysArray: true
            }) as RawQuery<TKeywords, TRanges>;

            return {
                query: q,
                offset: o,
                limit: l,
                expand: e,
                view: v,
                conditions: {
                    include: extractInclude(query),
                    exclude: query.exclude
                }
            };
        });

export const KEYWORDS = [
    "edition",
    "version",
    "is-earliest-in-cycle",
    "is-latest-in-cycle",
    "is-latest"
] as const;

export const RANGES = ["cycle"] as const;

const BOOL = z.coerce.boolean().optional();

export const releaseInclude = (
    rawQuery: SearchParserResult & {
        text?: string[];
    } & Partial<Record<(typeof KEYWORDS)[number], Array<string>>> &
        Partial<
            Record<
                (typeof RANGES)[number],
                {
                    from: string;
                    to?: string | undefined;
                }
            >
        >
) => ({
    text: rawQuery.text,
    edition: rawQuery.edition,
    version: rawQuery.version,
    cycle: rawQuery.cycle,
    isEarliestInCycle: BOOL.parse(
        rawQuery["is-earliest-in-cycle"]?.[
            rawQuery["is-earliest-in-cycle"].length - 1
        ]
    ),
    isLatestInCycle: BOOL.parse(
        rawQuery["is-latest-in-cycle"]?.[
            rawQuery["is-latest-in-cycle"].length - 1
        ]
    ),
    isLatest: BOOL.parse(
        rawQuery["is-latest"]?.[rawQuery["is-latest"].length - 1]
    )
});

/** Nextjs search params */
const searchParams: { [key: string]: string | Array<string> | undefined } | undefined = {};

const releaseQuery = SEACH_QUERY(KEYWORDS, RANGES, releaseInclude).parse(searchParams);

releaseQuery.conditions.include;
//                      ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.version;
//                              ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.cycle;
//                              ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.include.isLatest;
//                              ^?

releaseQuery.conditions.exclude;
//                      ^?


Please do not just post some links to elsewhere, but rather a self-contained answer to the question.
